# Manipulating SVG files with C#

Tags: c#, xml, svg

I need to be able to edit the text and images of an SVG file that has been rendered in Adobe Illustrator.

How can I iterate through the elements of an SVG file, check for type = text, change the value, and save the file to disk? Is there any library available that could help me?

So far I've tried [this basic library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8207/SVGPad-Application-and-class-library-for-editing-S) but it doesn't do well with complex SVG structures.

Answer (score 1):

[SVG RENDERING ENGINE](http://svg.codeplex.com/)

I used this one for a project.
There were a few flaws but it did the job.

Answer (score 1):

This may be very late to answer but for the sake of others if they land in this page, You can use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). Here is the link to a similar question: [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

I have used it in my case where i needed to edit the svg string and replace some values like this:

```
 HtmlDocument theDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    theDocument.LoadHtml(svgChartImg1);

    HtmlNodeCollection theNodes = theDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tspan");
```

Here, the `svgChartImg1` is an svg xml string.